# HTML Image width seems fixed

Tags: html, css

I have the follwing image tag in my page:

```
<img 
style="border-radius: 2em; box-shadow: rgb(204, 204, 204) 3px 3px 8px 1px; height: 250px; width: 370px; overflow: hidden;" 
src="evil_dims.jpg" 
alt="An illustration of the various mountain bike dimensions">
```

The rendered image height respects the style, but not the width, which is always fixed at 200px.  Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you have some CSS rule using `!important` applying on it. inspect and report please.

Comment: Please provide a working, verifiable, minimal example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The elm-hot module that I am using creates a div around my app in development mode, which included a style to limit img tags' `max-width` value to 200px.  @vsync, thanks for the good tip about some other CSS value causing the issue.

My solution, was just to add a `maw-width` style attribute to the image.